# Can't close Window in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's my problem : I have my first WPF window, and I create a second when changing the value of the SelectedItem of a Combobox. And I want to close the window I created when the value is changed again. I tried this :

```
var cCEntityWindow = new Windows.CCEntityWindow(dptList);
cCEntityWindow.CloseWindow();
```

from the codebehind of my first Window, but it doesn't work, so I create a simple method in my second Window :

```
public void CloseWindow()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

and I call it from my first Window, but it doesn't work either, and I don't know why !

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `this.Close()` from the Window that you want to close, not from the other one. You could try this method, by passing the windowName

```
Window wintoclose = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == "Window Name");
wintoclose.Close();
```

Comment: My method "CloseWindow" is located on my window that I want to close, and I call it from the other one. I'll try your metod with the Window Name, otherwise.

Comment: Your method works, thank you for helping, I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Comment: When I use this it says `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
wintoclose was null.`

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan. may i know what should be the name of the window. within quotation marks? ""